# Confusion over use of “avoir” vs “être” in “ne rien avoir de”

Tags: grammaire, verbes

I just read this sentence and while I understand the meaning, I don't understand what is going on in terms of the grammar or the alternative meaning for *aura + rien*. Is there some construction here that I don't know of.

> Obtenir une place en quart de finale n'aura rien d'automatique.

Why *aura* and not *sera*? Why *rien* and not *pas*? Would *ne sera pas automatique* have the same meaning?

Comment: Welcome to French Language. I think this is a good first question. I've slightly modified the title as you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have these two forms:

> Obtenir une place en quart de finale **n'aura rien d'automatique**.
>
> Obtenir une place en quart de finale **ne sera pas automatique**.

The two have the same meaning.

The part *n'aura rien d'* is a conjugation of the exact expression: *ne rien avoir de*.

The nuance is that *n'aura rien d'* is stronger than *ne sera pas*: the former means that you are **really really** sure.

As @Aaron pointed on the comments, you can make a sentence with the same strength using “être” this way:

> Obtenir une place en quart de finale **ne sera en rien automatique**.

In this case, we prefer *avoir* because with *être* the sentence is longer.

Comment: It's possible to keep the same strength and stay closer to the original sentence by using `ne sera en rien X` instead of `ne sera pas X`

Comment: @Aaron I was comparing to answer to the question, but you're right, I'll edit my answer :)

Comment: (And as a side note to this explanation, of course, these constructions can be used with essentially any adjective with the same effect.)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, *"ne rien avoir d'automatique"* is equivalent to *"ne pas être automatique"*, though a little stronger.

So why *"ne rien"* and not *"ne pas"* ?
Well the opposite of the expression is *"avoir quelque chose d'automatique"* (rarely used, though)
and the opposite of *"avoir quelque chose"* is *"ne rien avoir"* (*"ne pas avoir quelque chose"* is logically correct but less elegant).